# Getting List Index out of range for Reading a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm Writing A code to read a csv file and find the value from the list then update it with "ABCD".
I have tried reading the csv using codecs but no luck.

```
    import csv
    import codecs
    Testnumber = ['xxxxxxxxx','yyyyyyy']
    i =0
    is_in_file = "BLACK LISTED NUMBER NOT FOUND IN THIS BASE"
    with open('D1_SD_ROI.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        my_content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for row in my_content:
              for A in row:
                  i=i+1 #couting number of loops eventually row number
                  for B in Testnumber:
                      if A == B:
                         print B
                         print i
                         r = csv.reader(csvfile)
                         lines = list(r)
                         lines[i-1][0] = 'ABCD'
                         writer = csv.writer(open('D1_SD_ROI.csv', 'w'))
                         writer.writerows(lines)
    print ("D1_SD_ROI")
    print is_in_file
```

I'm Getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sun.py", line 53, in
>       lines[i-1][0] = 'ABCD'   IndexError: list index out of
>   range

Comment: Why do you `import codecs`?  Add `print(lines)` and see why you get the exception.

Comment: @Lakshya Kumar I think you should initialize your i value to 1. Because first you are incremented it to 1 and the you are decremented it to 0 because of which it is not getting required line in CSV as csv file do not have line 0.

Comment: You appear to be re-writing the same file as you are reading, suggest you debug your code writing to a different filename and get it all working before overwriting the input file. Also rather than `r=csv.reader(csvfile)` which is attempting to reopen the file you are already reading (and possibly re-writing) why don’t you simply read all the rows from the file and close it, then process the read rows. And yes to doing debugging: simply print stuff out so you can see why you are getting the error. And maybe work with shortened data files until you get the logic working.